# перемещение картинки

Tags: javascript

Зачем от clientX и clientY вычитать getBoundingClientRect ?

1. clientX - это координаты курсора по X  при крике на элемент
2. clientY - это координаты курсора по Y  при крике на элемент
3. getBoundingClientRect  - Получить координаты элемента
4. Зачем от client вычитать getBoundingClientRect   ?

```js
var pole = document.getElementById('pole');
var mech = document.getElementById('mech');

pole.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  var poleCoords = pole.getBoundingClientRect();
  var poleCoords2 = {
    top: poleCoords.top,
    left: poleCoords.left
  }
  mech.style.top = event.clientY - poleCoords2.top - mech.offsetHeight / 2  + 'px';
  mech.style.left = event.clientX - poleCoords2.left - mech.offsetWidth / 2 + 'px';

})
```

```css
#pole{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #888;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

#mech{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  transition: 300ms;
}
```

```html
<div id="pole">
  <img src="https://play-apk.ru/uploads/posts/2018-09/1538310081_zen-ball-mini.png" alt="" id='mech'>
</div>
```

Comment: уберите вычитание и посмотрите что получится

Comment: @Stranger in the Q  пишет Error - ошибка

Comment: @Stranger in the Q координаты берутся относительно окна при клике по элементу ?

Comment: да `event.clientX `  относительно всего окна

Comment: ну и половину размера фишки вычитать

Comment: @Stranger in the Q также метод getBoundingClientRect относительно окна ? тогда будет  client -   getBoundingClientRect получим координаты элемента который нам нужен и присваиваем эти координаты мячу верно ?

Comment: @Stranger in the Q зависит перемещение от того мяч прописан абсолютно ?

Comment: да, это начинает его позиционировать  от угла страницы

Comment: @Stranger in the Q тогда получается мяч должен быть не только быть абсолютно но и прописать left и top 0 ?

Comment: получается надо вычитать потому что картинка внутри, я обратил на это внимание только когда начал делать сниппет в ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поля `clientX` и `clientY` из события это координаты относительно окна

Рекомендую использовать `pageX` и `pageY` вместо clientX`и`clientY, они учитывают скролл, проверьте в не развернутом сниппете:

Так же я вынес наружу картинку, мне показалось так ее легче позиционировать (ограничить полем).

PS: ну и половину размера фишки я вычел, чтобы она ориентирована была по центру относительно клика

```js
var pole = document.getElementById('pole');
var mech = document.getElementById('mech');
var p = pole.getBoundingClientRect();

pole.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var m = mech.getBoundingClientRect();
  let x = event.pageX - m.width/2;
  let y = event.pageY - m.height/2;
  mech.style.top = clamp(y, p.top, p.top+p.height-m.height) + 'px';
  mech.style.left = clamp(x, p.left, p.left+p.width-m.width) + 'px';
})

function clamp(val, min, max) {
  return Math.max(min, Math.min(val, max))
}
```

```css
body{
  margin:30px;
}

#pole{
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #888;
  border: 3px solid #000;
}

#mech{
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  top: 30px; 
  transition: 300ms;
}
```

```html
<div id="pole">
</div>
<img src="https://play-apk.ru/uploads/posts/2018-09/1538310081_zen-ball-mini.png" alt="" id='mech'>
```

Comment: что такое clamp?

Comment: метод, который ограничивает диапазон возможных значений минимумом и максимумом

Comment: Здравствуйте я изменил код, почему мяч не перемещается по карте, а скачет как попало ?

Comment: @Leks я посмотрю, как буду у компа

Comment: @Leks вы перепутали и в left задаете y а не x

Comment: поправил лучше не стало :(

Comment: а зачем Вы прибавляете половину размера фишки?

Comment: стоит absolute значит начинается в левом верхнем углу чтобы стало по середине надо разделить на половину ?

Comment: @Leks да, но почему прибавить а не вычесть?)

Comment: потому что я плаваю в этой теме :((

Comment: @Leks листик в клеточку и карандаш помогают

Comment: чтобы стало по центру надо поделить на половину затем кликаем по карте и становится на половину верно ?

Comment: если так затем нам тогда вычитать или прибавлять

Comment: Здравствуйте моя попытка номер ... неважно какая это попытка и так ... 1) e.clientX и e.clientY координаты элемента при событии  относительно экрана 2) getBoundingClientRect  - получить координаты элемента относительно  экрана  3) e.clientX и e.clientY - getBoundingClientRect получим элемент на котором весит обработчик 
  4)  e.clientX и e.clientY - elem.offsetHeight / 2 и elem.offsetWidth / 2 5) вычитаем половину элемента (половина чтобы стал по центру) т.к. он стоит absolute left: 0 и top: 0

Comment: скажите я правильно понял как работает перемещение картинки по полю ?

Comment: @Leks в целом да, в почему Вы сомневаетесь?)

Comment: маэстро не сказал свое слово ...

Comment: @ Stranger in the Q   coslole.log(), я такая команда ? :) так надежнее мне кажется ...

Comment: @Leks `console.log()` конечно же